# Prove that the function is a constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

If a mapping $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f^n(x)\equiv x$ on $[0,1]$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f(x)\equiv x$. Here $f^n(x):=\underbrace{(f(f(\dots(x)\dots))}_{n\text{ times}}$.

This is a problem 6a on page 170 from textbook ["Mathematical Analysis I"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540874518) by V. A. Zorich. So far, I've been able to prove this for $n=2$, after what I've conducted a proof by induction for all $n=2^k$. Here, I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** (Courtesy of @DanielFischer) Here is the proof that stands on the assumption that $f$ is strictly increasing (or strictly *decreasing*, which can be considered symmetrically). Suppose that $f(x_0)>x_0$ (we can deal with the case when $f(x_0)<x_0$ similarly). Then we can prove that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $f^n(x_0)>x_0$, which contradicts the condition $f^n(x)\equiv x$. Let's carry out the proof by induction. The basis of the induction is case $n=1$, which is evidently $f^1(x_0)=f(x_0)>x_0$. Let $f^{n-1}(x_0)>x_0$. The induction step is as follows: $f^{n-1}(x_0)>x_0 \implies f^n(x_0)>f(x_0)>x_0$, which finishes the proof. The former inequity follows from the monotony of the function $f$; the second one is the basis case of the statement.

Please, correct me if I'm wrong. To finish, I would like to say that there are some things that I don't clearly understand:

1. How to prove that the function $f$ is monotone?
2. How the continuity of the function can be used (is hasn't been used so far)?
3. Is it somehow possible to prove that if the described statement is true for $n=n_0$, then it is true for $n=n_0-1$, which would finish my initial 'proof by induction' idea?

Comment: What is the range for $n$ ?

Comment: Your definition of $\;f^n\;$ still is unclear: is that "product" (but then it should be $\;f(x)\cdot f(x)\cdot\ldots\cdot f(x)\;$) , or composition??

Comment: Thanks for your comments, so far everything is fixed!

Comment: No @KonstantinSidorov, it is not. Read above , please.

Comment: Oh, **now** it is properly defined !

Comment: I don't think so :) I've just fixed _both_ issues in the post.

Comment: You said you proved for $\;n=2\;$ and then you tried induction and got stuck. Would you mind showing your work?

Comment: The idea for induction proof is as follows: $f^{2^{n+1}}(x)=f^{2^n}(f^{2^n}(x))$. Let $F(x):=f^{2^n}(x)$. Since we know that the statement is true for $n=2$, we can say that $F(x)\equiv x$ (we can easily verify that function $F=f^{2^n}$ satisfies the conditions of our theorem). So, by induction, we have that $f(x)\equiv x$.

Comment: Hint: $f$ must be strictly increasing. Suppose you had $f(x_0) \neq x_0$ for some $x_0$. What can you deduce about $f^n(x_0)$?